# Access network folder from hosted website

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, network-programming, local-network

I have developed one web application in c#(asp.net) and hosted in a server(say Server1). The application want the read and write access to a folder located in another server(network path) say server2. I can open the folder from server1 in windows explorer by typing the network path. But in application no access error is occurring(System.Unauthorisedexception). I dont know what access to which user I want to provide? Please help me.

Comment: To closevoters: this should be duplicate of one of many similar questions when hitting "NTLM one hop hell" (for authenticated users) or simply not configuring app pool properly. Unlikely can be helped on ServerFault.com. If OP provides details on type of authentication used in the app - try to find good duplicate instead.

Answer (score 1):

Run your web application under an account that can access the folder on server2.  Change the `Identity` of the `Application Pool`; more details at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I did it but still same exception.